# I encountered zipfile.BadZipFile : Bad CRC-32 for file'torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so'

Tags: installation, virtual-environment

While I am install anaconda virtual environment, I got some error.

The commands were :
conda create --name OSX python=3.7
conda activate OSX
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113

And this error was emerged :
zipfile.BadZipFile : Bad CRC-32 for file'torch/lib/libtorch_cuda_cu.so'

I want to know why and to fix this problem.

I searched this issue on google